# Colorbox within a megamenu not working properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox, megamenu

Megamenu: http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-megamenu-2/

Here's a little example of the problem: http://kennylam.net/WIP/sandbox/example1/index.html

What the problem is, when the colorbox is called from a direct link as an iframe, it works perfectly fine. However, when I try to call it from the megamenu drop down, it just opens the page not using colorbox. I've taken a look at the coding but I'm not too good with Javascript myself.

Can someone take a look and see whats going on?

Thanks.

Comment: So I've narrowed it down to this line `e.stopPropagation();` in jquery.megamenu.js... When I remove it, it works perfectly. Is it safe to remove this line?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'/>
    <title>ColorBox Examples</title>
    <style>
        body{font:12px/1.2 Verdana, sans-serif; padding:0 10px;}
        a:link, a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#416CE5; border-bottom:1px solid #416CE5;}
        h2{font-size:13px; margin:15px 0 0 0;}
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/jquery.megamenu.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascripts/jquery.megamenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //why not move the megamenu includes (the css and js files) above and init it here
            $(".megamenu").megamenu();
            //now try to bind the colorbox
            //this is the one that is being used on your example page
            $(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});

            //if that is still not working you may have to unbind the click function from the a tag inside the mega menu

        });
    </script>
</script>


</head>
<body>
    <h1>ColorBox Demonstration</h1>

    <p><a class='iframe' href="http://threadless.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>


        <ul class="megamenu">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">Colorbox within megamenu</a>

    <div style="width: 500px;">
      <p><a class='iframe' href="http://threadless.com">Outside Webpage (Iframe)</a></p>


      </table>
    </div>
  </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```